# select checkboxes dynamically asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I want to select `checkbox` dynamically of a `datagrid`, if `datagrid` contains the matching `value` in `dataset`. I m binding `datagrid` when  user selects a value of a `dropdownlist`.

To achieve this I have written following code.

```
protected void dgAvailableCandidates_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dsSelectedCandidates = (DataSet)Session["SelectedCandidatesDataSet"];

        if (dsSelectedCandidates.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgAvailableCandidates.Items.Count; i++)
            {
               string indRow = dgAvailableCandidates.DataKeys[i].ToString();

               if (indRow == dsSelectedCandidates.Tables[1].Rows[i]["fk_recId"].ToString())
               {
                    CheckBox shouldCheck = (CheckBox)dgAvailableCandidates.Items[i].FindControl("chkbox_SelectCandidate");
                    shouldCheck.Checked = true;
               }

             }
        }

    }
```

I have created a stored procedure that returns two `datatables`, `tables0` is to `bind` `datagrid` and `table1` holds `recordIds` that are already available in `database table` as `selected or bit value (1)`.

My issue is here, when `datagrid` doesn't find a `value` in `table1` it throws an `exception` 'there is no matching row'. How should I fix this `exception`

Thanks!

Comment: You should check the existence of row in table1, before directly using its value, that will solve your problem.

Comment: @Dinesh Prajapati a little code would help me best to understand your hint.. thanks!

Comment: In which line of code (from above code) the exception is thrown?

Comment: this one `if (indRow == dsSelectedCandidates.Tables[1].Rows[i]["fk_recId"].ToString())`  I have used an array list but then it threw an index out of bound error. ...

Answer (score 0):

I have done at my end using telerik grid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_OnItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" TableLayout="Fixed" DataKeyNames="fk_recId">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ShipName" DataField="data_dummy"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Check">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb"/>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                AnotherSample();
                BindTable();
            }
        }
        private void BindTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new []{new DataColumn("fk_recId"),new DataColumn("data_dummy")});
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["fk_recId"] = i + 1;
                dr["data_dummy"] = "data" + i + 1;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
            RadGrid1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void RadGrid1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
            {
                GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("fk_recId").ToString();
                if(((DataTable)ViewState["dt"]).AsEnumerable().Any(i=>i["fk_recId2"].ToString()== strID))
                {
                    CheckBox shouldCheck = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cb");
                    shouldCheck.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }


        private void AnotherSample()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("fk_recId2"), new DataColumn("data_dummy") });
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["fk_recId2"] = i + 1;
            dr["data_dummy"] = "data" + i + 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        DataRow drq = dt.NewRow();
        drq["fk_recId2"] = 100;
        drq["data_dummy"] = "data";
        dt.Rows.Add(drq);
        ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    }
```

Comment: thanks so much for your kind efforts. I have no idea regarding `telerik`, could you please give an equivalent `c#` code for `dg_OnItemDataBound`  Thanks

Comment: please run my snippet at your end and modify it accordingly and let me know..actually I am busy in my project sorry @NikhilG There are nice help docs located in  telerik.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below condition to check the existence of row before accessing the row from index.

```
// This condition will check the existence of row before accessing its value.
if(dsSelectedCandidates.Tables[1].Rows.Count > i)
{
    if (indRow == dsSelectedCandidates.Tables[1].Rows[i]["fk_recId"].ToString())
        {
           CheckBox shouldCheck = (CheckBox)dgAvailableCandidates.Items[i].FindControl("chkbox_SelectCandidate");
           shouldCheck.Checked = true;
        }
}
```